# Bootstrap Alert na validação de campos

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

O formulário contém uma validação para campos em branco com um alert do Twitter-Bootstrap no evento "on.click" do jQuery, quando clico no botão pela primeira vez no botão "Cadastrar" o alert é exibido, porém se clicar novamente no botão "Cadastrar" e o campo ainda estiver em branco, o alert não exibe novamente.

Resumo do formulário:

```
<form role='form' id='formCad' name='formCad' method='post'>
  <p><input type='text' id='input1' name='input1'></p>
  <br>
  <p><input type='text' id='input2' name='input2'></p>
  <br>
  <button id='btnCad' class='btn btn-default'>Cadastrar</button>
</form>

<div style="display:none;" class="alert alert-warning floating_alert alert1"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button><strong style="color: red;">Atenção!</strong> Preencha o campo input1</div>

<div style="display:none;" class="alert alert-warning floating_alert alert2"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button><strong style="color: red;">Atenção!</strong> Preencha o campo input2</div>
```

O script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("button#btnCad").on('click', function(){

    var input1 = $("#input1").val();
    var input2 = $("#input2").val();

    if(input1 == "") {
      $(".alert1").fadeTo(3000,500).slideUp(500,function(){
        $(".alert1").slideUp(500);
        $(".alert1").remove();
      });
      $( "#input1" ).focus();
      return false;
    }

    if(input2 == "") {
      $(".alert2").fadeTo(3000,500).slideUp(500,function(){
        $(".alert2").slideUp(500);
        $(".alert2").remove();
      });
      $( "#input2" ).focus();
      return false;
    }

  });

});
</script>
```

O exemplo está no https://jsfiddle.net/qhg4v7x1/

Comment: Encontrei o erro, substitui .remove(); por .hide();

Comment: Você não precisa nem do `hide()`, o `.slideUp()` já esconde o seu elemento, e faz isso com a animação.